# Executing C++ object file on web server

Tags: php, c++, web-hosting

While working on localhost, I am executing C++ object file from php file using `exec()` call. The object file then send request to daemon process, which is also one executable file;works as server(I need to execute it manually so that it remains in listening mode i.e. `./server`).

Now I want to put my php file as a website on internet. Do I need any specific hosting plan or general plan like [enter link description here](http://www.net4.in/net4app/aspx/hosting/buyhosting.aspx) is sufficient?

My needs are php, mysql, ajax, jquery, JS, Executing c, c++ files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a c++ question.

Make sure you have the right permissions to execute the file. Remember, php executes as the 
`www-data` user.

`chmod a+x` to grand everyone *execution* permissions.

Then add the location of `./server` in your path and simply `exec()` it.

Comment: Will linux webhosting which allow php suffice my need?

Comment: @Karimkhan Yeah, it will but you'll have to buy a dedicated linux system. If you can't afford a dedicated system, call them and make sure they allow `exec()`. Plus they must provide a way to add the folder in which `server` will reside into the `path`.

Comment: Did you mean linux hosting plan by "Dedicated linux system" or cloud space?

Comment: @Karimkhan Cloud space is remote drive space, it has nothing to do with Linux. A dedicated server is a rack-motherboard linked with a datacenter which -usually- has linux or bsd installed to serve one user only.

Comment: Thanks, but i never come accross this. Can you please give me some link where thing I want could be available?